# Plotting arrows at the edges of a curve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

Inspired by [this question](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/396/plotting-arrows-at-the-edges-of-a-curve) at ask.sagemath, what is the **best** way of adding arrows to the end of curves produced by `Plot`, `ContourPlot`, etc...? These are the types of plots seen in high school, indicating the curve continues off the end of the page.

After some searching, I could not find a built-in way or up-to-date package to do this. (There is [ArrowExtended](http://www.scientificarts.com/arrowextended.html), but it's quite old).

The solution given in the ask.sagemath question relies on the knowledge of the function and its endpoints and (maybe) the ability to take derivatives. Its translation into Mathematica is

```
f[x_] := Cos[12 x^2]; xmin = -1; xmax = 1; small = .01; 
Plot[f[x],{x,xmin,xmax}, PlotLabel -> y==f[x], AxesLabel->{x,y},
  Epilog->{Blue,
    Arrow[{{xmin,f[xmin]},{xmin-small,f[xmin-small]}}],
    Arrow[{{xmax,f[xmax]},{xmax+small,f[xmax+small]}}]
  }]
```

[image: arrow cos(12 x^2)]

An alternative method is to simply replace the `Line[]` objects generate by `Plot[]` with `Arrow[]`.  For example

```
Plot[{x^2, Sin[10 x], UnitStep[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, {Thick, Blue}},
  (*AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.03],*) PlotRange -> All] /. 
 Line[x__] :> Sequence[Arrowheads[{-.04, .04}], Arrow[x]]
```

[image: multiple plots]

But this has the problem that any discontinuities in the lines generate arrow heads where you don't want them (this can often be fixed by the option `Exclusions -> None`). More importantly, this approach is hopeless with `CountourPlot`s. Eg try

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^3 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 1}] /. 
  Line[x__] :> Sequence[Arrowheads[{-.04, .04}], Arrow[x]]
```

(the problems in the above case can be fixed by the rule, e.g., `{a___, l1_Line, l2_Line, b___} :> {a, Line[Join[l2[[1]], l1[[1]]]], b}` or by using appropriate single headed arrows.).

As you can see, neither of the above (quick hacks) are particularly robust or flexible. Does anyone know an approach that is?

Comment: I can suggest to find points generated by Plot lying on/out

Comment: @Alexey: I'm not quite sure what you're suggesting...

Comment: @Simon I apologize, the sentence is incomplete. In the case of discontinuities I can suggest to find points lying on the edges of `PlotRange`. For example: `xmin = -2 Pi; xmax = Pi;
Plot[Tan[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, 
  Exclusions -> {Cos[x] == 
     0}] /. {x_Line?(Abs[#[[1, 1, 1]] - xmin] < 1*^-6 && 
       Abs[#[[1, -1, 1]] - xmax] < 1*^-6 &) :> 
   Sequence[Arrowheads[{-.04, .04}], Arrow[x]], 
  x_Line?(Abs[#[[1, 1, 1]] - xmin] < 1*^-6 &) :> 
   Sequence[Arrowheads[{-.04, 0}], Arrow[x]], 
  x_Line?(Abs[#[[1, -1, 1]] - xmax] < 1*^-6 &) :> 
   Sequence[Arrowheads[{0, .04}], Arrow[x]]
  }`.

Comment: @Alexey: I thought that was what you meant. Thanks for the code - if you put it in an answer, I'll vote it up. It's something I also thought of, but what happens if the plot range means that a line exits the plot at the top or bottom instead of the sides? You'd have to extract the PlotRange from the generated plot and use that in the rules...

Comment: @Alexey: also, your code only works for "simple" graphics objects. The ContourPlot above generates the lines using a `GraphicsComplex`, so your distance test fails for such plots. :(

Comment: @Simon Recently found this http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~gianluca.gorni/Mma/Mma.html (not tested)

Comment: @belisarius: Nice find! I Had a quick look at it, it's a very nicely written package with code that is well integrated into the normal Mma functions. It only adds directional arrows to curves, not arrows at the ends of curves indicating that they continue. Nevertheless, using some of the functionality built into the package, you could probably add the option for arrows on the end of curves...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following seems to work, by sorting the segments first:

```
f[x_] := {E^-x^2, Sin[10 x], Sign[x], Tan[x], UnitBox[x], 
             IntegerPart[x], Gamma[x],
             Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}], {x, x^2}}; 

arrowPlot[f_] := 
 Plot[{#}, {x, -2, 2}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> .2] /.

 {Hue[qq__], a___, x___Line} :> {Hue[qq], a, SortBy[{x}, #[[1, 1, 1]] &]} /. 

 {a___,{Line[x___], d___, Line[z__]}} :> 
                           List[Arrowheads[{-.06, 0}], a, Arrow[x], {d}, 
                                             Arrowheads[{0, .06}], Arrow[z]] /. 

 {a___,{Line[x__]}}:> List[Arrowheads[{-.06, 0.06}], a, Arrow[x]] & /@ f[x];  

arrowPlot[f]
```

[image]

Comment: @belisarius : there was a question/answer few months ago how to make traditional 3d axes with arrows in Mathematica and I can't find it anymore, do you remember any keywords from it?

Comment: @Yaro found it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16498/traditional-axes-in-3d-mathematica-plots

Comment: ahh, it's on different site, that's why I couldn't find it...thanks!

Comment: @belisarius: I completely missed your series of revisions, thanks for all of the effort. It's looking good! Unfortunately, your sort fails for the `ContourPlot` given in the question, since it is constructed using a `GraphicsComplex` object. This can be fixed by using `Normal`. But then you still run into the problem that your rules don't like plots with 'Tooltip'...

Comment: @belisarius: I figured out what's wrong. The `Sequence[]` makes the `Tooltip` get way too many arguments. Replace `Sequence[]` with `List[]` and it's all good.

Comment: @Simon I really don't get the point of using it for ´ContourPlot´, as the lines there are not functions (in a mathematical sense) and could be even loops or anything more crazy.

Comment: @belisarius: but contours can still head off to infinity, and it might be nice to indicate that. Also, sometimes it's easier to use `ContourPlot` instead of figuring out some parametrization for `ParametricPlot` or using different regions for `Plot`.

Comment: @Simon As you said "it's a matter of taste". I feel arrows in a contour somewhat misleading. But if you like them, go ahead with it! :)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by both Alexey's comment and belisarius's answers, here's my attempt.

```
makeArrowPlot[g_Graphics, ah_: 0.06, dx_: 1*^-6, dy_: 1*^-6] := 
 Module[{pr = PlotRange /. Options[g, PlotRange], gg, lhs, rhs},
  gg = g /. GraphicsComplex -> (Normal[GraphicsComplex[##]] &);
  lhs := Or@@Flatten[{Thread[Abs[#[[1, 1, 1]] - pr[[1]]] < dx], 
                      Thread[Abs[#[[1, 1, 2]] - pr[[2]]] < dy]}]&;
  rhs := Or@@Flatten[{Thread[Abs[#[[1, -1, 1]] - pr[[1]]] < dx], 
                      Thread[Abs[#[[1, -1, 2]] - pr[[2]]] < dy]}]&;
  gg = gg /. x_Line?(lhs[#]&&rhs[#]&) :> {Arrowheads[{-ah, ah}], Arrow@@x};
  gg = gg /. x_Line?lhs :> {Arrowheads[{-ah, 0}], Arrow@@x};
  gg = gg /. x_Line?rhs :> {Arrowheads[{0, ah}], Arrow@@x};
  gg
  ]
```

We can test this on some functions

```
Plot[{x^2, IntegerPart[x], Tan[x]}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Thick]//makeArrowPlot
```

[image: Normal plots]

And on some contour plots

```
ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 + y^2 == 6, x^3 + y^3 == {1, -1}}, 
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] // makeArrowPlot
```

[image: contour plots]

One place where this fails is where you have horizontal or vertical lines on the edge of the plot;

```
Plot[IntegerPart[x],{x,-2.5,2.5}]//makeArrowPlot[#,.03]&
```

[image: fail!]

This can be fixed by options such as `PlotRange->{-2.1,2.1}` or `Exclusions->None`.

Finally, it would be nice to add an option so that each "curve" can arrow heads only on their boundaries. This would give plots like those in Belisarius's answer (it would also avoid the problem mentioned above). But this is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

The following construct has the advantage of not messing with the internal structure of the Graphics structure, and is more general than the one suggested in ask.sagemath, as it manage PlotRange and infinities better.

```
f[x_] = Gamma[x]

{plot, evals} = 
  Reap[Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRangePadding -> .2, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, f[x]}]]];

{{minX, maxX}, {minY, maxY}} = Options[plot, PlotRange] /. {_ -> y_} -> y; 
ev = Select[evals[[1]], minX <= #[[1]] <= maxX && minY <= #[[2]] <= maxY &];
seq = SortBy[ev, #[[1]] &];
arr = {Arrow[{seq[[2]], seq[[1]]}], Arrow[{seq[[-2]], seq[[-1]]}]};
```

[image]

```
Show[plot, Graphics[{Red, arr}]]
```

**Edit**

As a function:

```
arrowPlot[f_, interval_] := Module[{plot, evals, within, seq, arr},
   within[p_, r_] :=
    r[[1, 1]] <= p[[1]] <= r[[1, 2]] &&
     r[[2, 1]] <= p[[2]] <= r[[2, 2]];

   {plot, evals} = Reap[
     Plot[f[x], Evaluate@{x, interval /. List -> Sequence},
      Axes -> False,
      Frame -> True,
      PlotRangePadding -> .2,
      EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, f[x]}]]];

   seq = SortBy[Select[evals[[1]],
      within[#, 
        Options[plot, PlotRange] /. {_ -> y_} -> y] &], #[[1]] &];

   arr = {Arrow[{seq[[2]], seq[[1]]}], Arrow[{seq[[-2]], seq[[-1]]}]};
   Show[plot, Graphics[{Red, arr}]]
   ];

arrowPlot[Gamma, {-3, 4}]
```

Still thinking what is better for ListPlot & al.

Comment: Cool! How would this generalize, to say, a `ListPlot` of experimental data? (assuming you were lazy and didn't put the data into an interpolating function and then use `Plot` like above)?