# How can I make a directed arc of a circle (or a directed curve)?

Tags: geometry, wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to display a directed circular arc in Mathematica, using something as simple as `Arrow`. The best I have been able to come up with is this example that nails an `Arrow` onto one end of a circular arc. But I suspect there is a more direct way to achieve the same effect.

```
start=\[Pi];
Manipulate[
Graphics[{
   Arrow[{{Cos[\[Theta] + If[\[Theta] < start, .01, -.01]], 
           Sin[\[Theta] + If[\[Theta] < start, .01, -.01]]}, 
          {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}}],
   Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {start, \[Theta]}]},
PlotRange -> 2], 
{{\[Theta], .7 start}, 0, 2 start} 
           ]
```

[image: arrow]

`Arrow` accepts `BSplineCurves` and `BezierCurves`but I can't get them to stay on a circular arc.  `Tube` accepts the formula for a curve in 3D but I can't figure out how to get it to work in 2D.

All suggestions are welcome.  If your solution works for *any* *2D curve*, all the better!

---

#### Epilogue:

I learned quite a bit from the suggestions:
Mark McClure showed that `Arrow` itself can handle the demands when given a list of points.

yoda gave a fairly general solution using ParametricPlot.

I ended up finding belisarius' suggestions the most helpful.  His approach was to work on minor variations of familiar graphical objects.  In the end, I cautiously chose to define a new object, `arcArrow`, that employs the parameters of `Circle`: center, radius, {start,finish}.  `Unprotect` still scares me!  Anyway, here's what I settled with. I also stubbornly held on to some features of my original approach.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{  
   arcArrow[center, radius, {start, end}],
   PointSize[Large], Blue, If[showCenter, Point[center]]},
  PlotRange -> p, ImageSize -> 250],
 {{start, \[Pi]/2}, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], ImageSize -> Small},
 {{end, 0}, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], ImageSize -> Small},
 {{radius, 1}, 1/2, 4, ImageSize -> Small},
 {{center, {0, 0}}, {-p, -p}, {p, p}, Slider2D},
 {showCenter, {True, False}},

 Initialization :> {p = 3;
   arcArrow[a_, r_, {start_, end_}] :=
    {Circle[a, r, {start, end}], 
     Arrowheads[Medium],
     Arrow[{a + r {Cos[end + If[end < start, .01, -.01]], 
                   Sin[end + If[end < start, .01, -.01]]}, 
            a + r {Cos[end], Sin[end]}}]} }]
```

[image: final version]

---

Comment: This [link](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/a1547377410a64a5) might be of interest, in particular the workaround by Bill Rowe.

Comment: @TomD Yes. They are discussing just the issue I raised. One of the solutions corresponds to what I came up with. Another matches Mark McClure's suggestion. Funny, but when I thought of `Line` (or `Arrow`) very segmented images came to mind. I didn't think about really tiny segments!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using **Circle[ ]**:

```
f[s_Circle] := 
 s /. Circle[a_, r_, {start_, end_}] :>
      ({s,Arrow[{# - r/10^6 {-Sin@end, Cos@end}, #}]} &[a+r {Cos@end, Sin@end}]) 

Graphics@f[Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {4 Pi/3, 2 Pi}]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Redefining the default Circle[ ] behavior:

```
Unprotect[Circle];
Circle[a_: {0, 0}, r_: 1, {start_, end_}] :=
  Block[{$inMsg = True},
    {Circle[a, r, {start, end}],
     Circle[a, r, {start, end}] /. 
      Circle[aa_, 
        ar_, {astart_, aend_}] :> (Arrow[If[start < end, #, Reverse@#]] &@
             {# - r/10^6 {-Sin@end, Cos@end}, #} &
               [aa + ar {Cos@aend, Sin@aend}])}
    ] /; ! TrueQ[$inMsg];
Protect[Circle];
```

[image]

Comment: A very straightforward, clean approach. You hand `f` a graphics object (a circular arc). It returns the arc with an arrowhead.

Comment: @David That's the idea. if you have your program structured with _Circle[ ]_, you don't have to change that. And you may also redefine _Circle[ ]_ to do this automagically

Comment: @David  See edit for redefining the default Circle[ ] behavior

Comment: @belisarius The format is certainly more natural than `f[]`. I'm wondering, however: why not use `circle` rather than `Circle`? Don't you risk messing up the definition of Circle?

Comment: @David I did exactly that. I redefined **Circle[ ]** so that all your arcs will show arrows without any other program modification :)

Comment: @belisarius  Why did you add the line `Protect[Plot]` if it was `Circle` that you `Unprotect`ed?

Comment: @David because I copy-pasted  the code from another notebook. Blush!

Comment: @belisarius And I thought there was something very subtle that I wasn't getting!

Comment: @belisarius What if start > end?

Comment: @David see the new version :)

Comment: @belisarius Yep, that takes care of the arrowhead direction issue. I ended up being afraid to use `Unprotect`. But I learned much from your adherence to standard forms.

Comment: @David Well, I can't blame your fear. Modifying Mma symbols must be done with utmost care. Your solution is nice!

Answer (score 8):

You can also add an arrow to the end point of an arc like so:

```
circle[x_] = {Cos[x], Sin[x]};
ParametricPlot[{0.9 circle[x], 0.7 circle[x + Pi/3], 0.4 circle[-x]}, 
 {x, Pi/4, Pi/2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Axes -> False] 
/.Line[x__] :> Sequence[Arrowheads[.03], Arrow[x]]
```

[image]

This is probably much easier to control, as you can set the radius and arc length programmatically and just replace the arrows in the end.

You should also take a look at the discussion on [adding arrows at the edges of a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074921/plotting-arrows-at-the-edges-of-a-curve). There are a lot of good approaches there, perhaps better than this one. I personally found [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074921/plotting-arrows-at-the-edges-of-a-curve/5132072#5132072) to his own question to be a pretty nifty little function that I have in my little 'functions from the internet' collection, and have used it more than once to place arrows on graphs that continue outside the plot.

**EDIT**

The way I've defined it above, it places an arrow at the end of the line. For e.g., if you plot a line from L to R, it places it on the right and left otherwise. So in the example, positive increase in x is counter-clockwise and hence the arrows in that direction. Increase in the negative dir will produce a clockwise arrow. To avoid a second plot command, I simply changed `x` to `-x` in the third function in the list, which produced the same effect in the golden colored curve.

More generally, you can change orientation of the arrows by changing the inputs to `Arrowheads` as follows:

***Arrows going the other way round***

[image]

***Arrows on both ends***

[image]

***Inverted arrowheads***

[image]

Comment: Very nice! It handles any parametric plot. I couldn't figure out what the delayed replacement rule was doing until I looked under the hood with `InputForm@ParametricPlot[{0.9 circle[x], 0.7 circle[x + Pi/3], 0.4 circle[-x]}, {x, Pi/4, Pi/2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1},Axes -> True]` and found `Line`.   Thanks also for the interesting link on arrows.

Answer (score 7):

`Arrow` accepts a list of points of arbitrary length.  Thus, perhaps something like so.

```
Manipulate[Graphics[
  Arrow[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, T, Sign[T] Pi/100}]],
  PlotRange -> 1.1], {{T, 0}, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: @Mark Thanks. That's certainly more elegant than my approach.

Comment: The path I want to implement is actually a chain of circular arcs in which the center and radius change parameters every so often.  A table can easily accumulate such changes; it just takes more points (although ones that have been produced by a slightly different set of parameters).

Comment: @Mark Only counter-clockwise arrows?

Comment: @David Why only clock-wise?  If you place a minus sign in front of the `Sin[t]`, you'll find that the arrow travels in the other direction.  You can replace `{Cos[t],Sin[t]}` with any formula you want to generate all manner of curves.

Comment: @Mark. Yes, I see. But because I'd like to control it via a slider, it's not clear how to implement it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @David - See edited code using the groovy `Sign` function to control step direction.

Comment: Hmm... I don't get a flashing screen. The arrow simply changes to a dot at t=0 on my great big Mac.  One could certainly write a function that generates a `Graphics` object as a function of `t` with a specialized result at t=0. In that way you could generate any particular special picture you want then.