# Arrows for the axes

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How to get arrows for the axes when using the command Plot in Mathematica?

Thanks for any helpful answers.

Comment: By Simon, for example http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/cec6c6757e321ec5

Comment: You might also be interested in the answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074921/plotting-arrows-at-the-edges-of-a-curve) SO question (_Plotting Arrows at the End of a Curve_), also posted by Simon

Answer (score 19):

For 2D plots such as generated by Plot the following works great:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.07]]
```

[image]

or with custom arrow heads:

```
h = Graphics[Line[{{-1, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/2}}]];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{{Automatic, Automatic, h}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Building on Sjoerd's answer,

a plot such as

[image]

may be obtained as follows (for example):

```
       Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2\[Pi], 2 \[Pi]},

 AxesStyle-> { 

Directive[{Red,
Arrowheads[{{-0.06,0(*Xleft*),{Graphics[{
Polygon[
{{-1,0.5`},{0,0},{-1,-0.5`}}]}],0.98`}},
{0.03,.9(*Xright*),{Graphics[{
Polygon[
{{-1,0.5`},{0,0},{-1,-0.5`}}]}],0.98`}}}]}], 

Directive[{Blue,
Arrowheads[{{-0.05,0(*Ydown*),{Graphics[{
Polygon[
{{-1,0.5`},{0,0},{-1,-0.5`}}]}],0.98`}},{0.03,.8(*Yup*),{Graphics[{
Polygon[
{{-1,0.5`},{0,0},{-1,-0.5`}}]}],0.98`}}}]}
]}]
```

There are nice examples of arrowheads given in `Drawings Tools` and `Graphics Inspector`.  There are probably much better ways of getting the info but I [annotate a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5744117/499167) with an arrow that I like and then abstract (using a [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744117/saving-plot-annotations/5753555#5753555) from Simon):

```
Cases["Paste-Graphic_Here", Arrowheads[___], Infinity]
```

To give another example:

[image]

The code is as follows

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2\[Pi],2 \[Pi]}, 
AxesStyle-> { Directive[{Red,

Arrowheads[{{-0.06,0.1(*Xleft*),
{Graphics[{arrowhead}]/.arrowhead-> arrowhead2,0.98`}},
{0.05,0.95(*Xright*),
{Graphics[{arrowhead}],0.98`}}}]/.arrowhead-> arrowhead4}], 

Directive[{Blue,
Arrowheads[{{-0.05,0(*Ydown*),
{Graphics[{arrowhead}]/.arrowhead-> arrowhead3,0.98`}},{0.03,.8(*Yup*),
{Graphics[{arrowhead}]/.arrowhead-> arrowhead1,0.98`}}}]}

]}]
```

**where**

```
arrowhead1=Polygon[{{-1,0.5`},{0,0},{-1,-0.5`}}];

arrowhead2=Polygon[{{-1.5833333333333333`,0.4166666666666667`},{-1.5410500000000003`,0.369283333333333`},{-1.448333333333333`,0.255583333333333`},{-1.3991000000000005`,0.18721666666666673`},{-1.3564666666666663`,0.11826666666666673`},{-1.3268499999999999`,0.05408333333333341`},{-1.3166666666666667`,0.`},{-1.3268499999999999`,-0.048950000000000195`},{-1.3564666666666663`,-0.11228333333333372`},{-1.3991000000000005`,-0.18353333333333333`},{-1.448333333333333`,-0.2562833333333335`},{-1.5410500000000003`,-0.38048333333333345`},{-1.5833333333333333`,-0.43333333333333335`},{0.`,0.`},{-1.5833333333333333`,0.4166666666666667`},{-1.5833333333333333`,0.4166666666666667`}}];

arrowhead3=Polygon[{{-1,0.5`},{0,0},{-1,-0.5`},{-0.6`,0},{-1,0.5`}}];

arrowhead4={{FaceForm[GrayLevel[1]],Polygon[{{-0.6`,0},{-1.`,0.5`},{0.`,0},{-1.`,-0.5`},{-0.6`,0}}],Line[{{-0.6`,0},{-1.`,0.5`},{0.`,0},{-1.`,-0.5`},{-0.6`,0}}]}};

arrowhead5=Polygon[{{-0.6582278481012658`,-0.43037974683544306`},{0.`,0.`},{0.`,0.`},{0.`,0.`},{0.`,0.`},{0.`,0.`},{-0.6455696202531646`,0.43037974683544306`},{-0.4810126582278481`,0.`},{-0.6582278481012658`,-0.43037974683544306`},{-0.6582278481012658`,-0.43037974683544306`}}];
```

A list of arrowheads 1 to 5:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[**Here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16498/traditional-axes-in-3d-mathematica-plots) you have a solution posted in https://math.stackexchange.com/

As the solution in the reference is for Plot3D, here I modified (but not improved) it for Plot[ ]:

```
axes[x_, y_, f_, a_] := 
 Graphics[Join[{Arrowheads[a]}, 
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ {{x, 0}, {0, y}}, 
   {Text[Style["x", FontSize -> Scaled[f]], {0.9*x, 0.1*y}], 
    Text[Style["y", FontSize -> Scaled[f]], {0.1 x, 0.95*y}]
   }]]

Show[Plot[Exp[-x^2], {x, -2, 2}, 
       Axes -> None, 
       PlotRange -> {{-2.1, 2.1}, {-.1, 1.1}}], 
     axes[2, 1, 0.05, 0.02]
]
```

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with them then? Actually, I'd say that the axes above are a bit unusual. In 2D plots you don't normally see curves in areas without axes.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Yes, I know. I was almost finished formatting my answer and uploading images when I got a notification that you had just posted the exact same answer :(